# fetching rows from ajax and append in existing last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**This is my view of page.**

[image]

**This is the code of above page.**
When i click on any page button i got that page script in alert(data). but i want from here only rows of this page and

> append below the existing rows

.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('button[id^="next"]').on('click', function() {  
        var page = ($(this).attr('value'));
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'index.php?act=product',
          data: ({page:page}),
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data); // what to do i here. please suggest me.
          }
        });
     });
    });
</script>
```

> My existing rows is here

```
 <tbody>

<?php foreach($products as $product){ ?>

<tr>
    <td class="text-center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product['sku']; ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product['status']; ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product['date_time']; ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><a href="index.php?act=editproduct&id=<?php echo $product['product_id'];?>"> Edit</a></td>              
 </tr>**//here in the last but this is dynamic <tr>.**

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
```

**Sample of alert(data) is below.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!----amit bootstrap---->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/css/style.css">
        <script src="view/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="view/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--validation code start------->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="view/css/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="view/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="view/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="view/js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
        <!-- amit bootstrap end ---->
    </head> 
<script>
    function ToggleAll(source) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkbox[]');
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
</script>   
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('button[id^="next"]').on('click', function() {  
        var page = ($(this).attr('value'));
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'index.php?act=product',
          data: ({page:page}),
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          }
        });
     });
    });
</script>
<body>
 <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>View Upload Product</h2>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 menu">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 text-right"><a href="index.php?act=upload"> Back </a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 text-right"><a href="index.php?act=logout"> Logout </a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        </div><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <form role="form" name="deleteproduct" id="deleteproduct" method="POST" action="index.php?act=deleteproduct" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">     </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><button  class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">Delete</button></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-center"><input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='ToggleAll(this);'></th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">SKU</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Date & Time</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="27"></td>
                                        <td class="text-center">test</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">123</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">Y</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">2015-08-14 17:38:29</td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><a href="index.php?act=editproduct&id=27"> Edit</a></td>                
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="28"></td>
                                        <td class="text-center">test2</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">1qas</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">Y</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">2015-08-14 17:38:29</td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><a href="index.php?act=editproduct&id=28"> Edit</a></td>                
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <button  class="btn btn-default btn-md" type="submit" name="magento" value="magento">Magento Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
                <button class='btn page' id='next1' value='1'>1</button><button class='btn page' id='next2' value='2'>2</button>            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the ajax response?

Comment: yes why not wait a minute.

Comment: So response it's a whole page? then you will need to parse the rows and append to your DOM,

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your ajax response format, if it where json, it could be done like this:

```
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'index.php?act=product',
          data: ({page:page}),
          success: function(data) {
            var my_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < my_data.length; i++) {
                var my_row = $('<tr>');
                var my_html = '<td>'+my_data[i].field+'</td>';
                my_html += '<td>'+my_data[i].field2+'</td>';
                my_row.html(my_html);
                $('tbody').append(my_row);
            }
          }
        });
```

EDIT: But given your code, you need to parse the  and append them to your DOM

-EDIT: If you need to make the call just once:

```
var requestDone = false;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('button[id^="next"]').on('click', function() {  
         if( !requestDone) {
           $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: 'index.php?act=product',
              data: ({page:page}),
              success: function(data) {
                  var my_rows = $(data).find('tbody').html();
                  $('tbody').append(my_rows);
                  requestDone = true;
              }
           });
         }
       });
    });
```

Comment: You're wellcome, maybe an upvote would be nice, too :)

Comment: I voted already but stackoverflow is saying that after my 15 reputation it will be count.

Comment: Hi Toni, this ajax code add page every time on click but it should be add only one time.

Comment: Use a boolean to know if you made the request or not